# Pull information in different repositories in git

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have n repositories in which these have the same backend but have different front end. I would like to have a way to when I commit a new change propagate the new changes in the other repositories.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have *one* repository for the backend and have each front end pull the backend as a dependency - either through submodules or through the language's specific way of managing this.

Comment: @Makoto sounds like your comment should be a answer... with a example :)

Comment: I'd like to know the best way to push/pull in all submodules when I make a change in one submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you to pull changes from repoN to other N-1 repositories (assume the changes is on `master` branch).

#### Option1: submoduels

First, add other N-1 repositories as submodule for repoN by `git submodule add /path/to/repo1`,…,`git submodule add /path/to/repoN-1`.

Second, add repoN as the other remote for these N-1 repositories by `git submodule foreach 'git remote add repoN /path/to/repoN'`.

Finally, after you commit changes for repoN, you can execute `git submodule foreach 'git fetch repoN && git cherry-pick repoN/master'`.

#### Option2: shell script

You can use shell script to pull changes to other repositories. Assume you commit changes in repo N, now you can execute script to update other N-1 repositories (firstly, you need to add remote for these n-1 repositories by `git remote add repoN /path/to/repoN`). The script should contains the functions as:

```
cd /pth/to/repo1
git fetch repoN 
git cherry-pick remoN/master -X theirs

cd /pth/to/repo2
git fetch repoN 
git cherry-pick remoN/master -X theirs
…
cd /pth/to/repoN-1
git fetch repoN
git cherry-pick remoN/master -X theirs
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment help me a lot.